# Fatal error: Class Worldpay not found

Tags: php, payment, worldpay

I am using Worldpay template form for payment. After enter the card detail i got token form Worldpay. But when i redirect to payment page for order completion i did not found the class Worldpay.

```
$token = $_POST["token"];
$worldpay = new Worldpay('Service code here *********');
```

Token received but i am getting error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Worldpay' not found in index.php on line 4
```

I have not include any PHP class. is i need to add class on top. if yes which one thanks

Comment: You must have to include those class file over index.php. .i.e include_once('worldpay.class.php');

Comment: I am looking but i did not find any on worldpay website.

Answer (score 1):

That error is caused by the fact that you are not including any PHP class.
What you need to have is the entire Worldpay PHP library which can be downloaded from Worldpay's documentation site
https://online.worldpay.com/docs/code-libraries

Download the latest PHP library and make sure you include the Worldpay class in your "complete" php script:

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/Worldpay.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/Connection.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/AbstractAddress.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/DeliveryAddress.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/BillingAddress.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/AbstractOrder.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/Order.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/APMOrder.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/Error.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/OrderService.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/TokenService.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/Utils.php');
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/WorldpayException.php');
```

Make sure that in the /lib directory you have all of the scripts provided in the library.

You might still encounter the same issue depending on your php settings. In which case just comment out all of the namespace declarations in Worldpay's library files.

e.g.

```
// namespace Worldpay;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and to solve it I just included the link to the content delivery network address for the WorldPay library. This has to be referenced **before** the form, preferably at the top of the page. Link below;

```
 <script src='https://cdn.worldpay.com/v1/worldpay.js'></script>
```

Make sure you do not defer the loading of this JavaScript as it calls other files (is a library) as Martin pointed out.

Here is a link to the online documentation for WorldPay integration: https://beta.developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpop/own-form

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the Worldpay PHP libraries via the Composer route you will can put "use" statements near the top of your script after the lines to initialise the Composer managed 3rd party libraries. e.g.

```
use \Worldpay\Worldpay;
use \Worldpay\WorldpayException;
etc..
```